# How can I remove the # from a link href with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have this HTML:

```
<ul id="tabs"> 
    <li class="active"><a href="#northern_california">Northern California</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#southern_california">Southern California</a></li> 
</ul>
```

When I click the link I need to set a cookie to the value of the href without the #. This jQuery code isn't working:

```
$('#tabs a').click(function() {
    var active_region = $(this).attr('href').replace('#','');
    $.cookie('active_region',active_region,{path:'/'});
});
```

It sets the cookie to "#southern_california"; I need it to be "southern_california".

Comment: This should be working: http://jsfiddle.net/cTLQF/ Are you sure you cleared your cookies first before checking?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/TZkzg/ (I pasted in the cookie plugin code so scroll down to the bottom)

Comment: That should work.  Have you breakpointed the `$.cookie` line and verified the value of active_region?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tabs a').click(function() {
    var active_region = $(this).attr('href');
    if(active_region && active_region[0] == '#') 
       active_region = active_region.substr(1);

    $.cookie('active_region',active_region,{path:'/'});
});
```